# pass data to parent component after changing the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a custom picker Component, I want to pass data to parent after each change in state, I tried using `this.props.onChange` in the render method and pass states that I want to use in the parent.
When I use `consol.log` it logs the values that I want but when I use 
`value=> this.setState({value})`  I get this error:

`Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

here is my code:

```
export default class DatePicker extends React.Component {


    state = {
        days:31,
        month: 1,
        day : 1,
        year : 9500
    };



    render() {
        const {day, month, year} = this.state

        this.props.onChange({day,month, year})
        return(

               <View style={{flex:1 ,flexDirection:'row'}}> 

               <Picker
                         selectedValue={this.state.year}
                         enabled={false}
                         style={{height: 10, width: 70}}
                         onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                             this.setState({year: itemValue})
                         }>
                        {[...Array(12).keys()].map(i => <Picker.Item label={(i+9500).toString()} value={i+9500} /> )}

                         </Picker>

                         <Picker
                         selectedValue={this.state.text}
                         enabled={false}
                         style={{height: 0, width: 70}}
                         onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                             this.setState({text: itemValue, days: itemValue < 6? 31 : 30 })
                         }>
                         {date.map(i => <Picker.Item label={i.label} value={i.value} /> )}

                         </Picker>
                         <Picker
                         selectedValue={this.state.day}
                         enabled={false}
                         style={{height: 10, width: 70}}
                         onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                             this.setState({day: itemValue})
                         }>
                        {[...Array(this.state.days).keys()].map(i => <Picker.Item label={(i+1).toString()} value={i+1} /> )}

                         </Picker>

                         </View>

        )

    }
}
```

## **TL;DR**

I want to create a component which has OnChange props like `<TextInput>` What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You are getting this error because when ever you are updating the parent with `this.setState`, you are re-rendering the parent, causing the child compoenent to also re-render, and in the child render you again calling the onChange on parent causing an infinite loop of rendering. you should move the onChange handler to a method. so it will only render on pressing key/pick new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function that will handle the values and pass them to the parent

```
handleOnChange = value => {
  const data = {
    ...this.state,
    ...value
  }

  this.setState(data)
  this.props.onChane(data)
```

}

then on `onValueChange` use that handler instead of `this.setState`

```
<Picker
   selectedValue={this.state.day}
   enabled={false}
   style={{height: 10, width: 70}}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
   this.handleOnChange({day: itemValue})
 }>
```

the full code will be like this

```
export default class DatePicker extends React.Component {


state = {
    days:31,
    month: 1,
    day : 1,
    year : 9500
};

handleOnChange = value => {
  const data = {
    ...this.state,
    ...value,
  }

  this.setState(data)
  this.props.onChange(data)
}

render() {
    const {day, month, year} = this.state

    this.props.onChange({day,month, year})
    return(

           <View style={{flex:1 ,flexDirection:'row'}}> 

           <Picker
                     selectedValue={this.state.year}
                     enabled={false}
                     style={{height: 10, width: 70}}
                     onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                         this.handleOnChange({year: itemValue})
                     }>
                    {[...Array(12).keys()].map(i => <Picker.Item label={(i+9500).toString()} value={i+9500} /> )}

                     </Picker>

                     <Picker
                     selectedValue={this.state.text}
                     enabled={false}
                     style={{height: 0, width: 70}}
                     onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                         this.handleOnChange({text: itemValue, days: itemValue < 6? 31 : 30 })
                     }>
                     {date.map(i => <Picker.Item label={i.label} value={i.value} /> )}

                     </Picker>
                     <Picker
                     selectedValue={this.state.day}
                     enabled={false}
                     style={{height: 10, width: 70}}
                     onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                         this.handleOnChange({day: itemValue})
                     }>
                    {[...Array(this.state.days).keys()].map(i => <Picker.Item label={(i+1).toString()} value={i+1} /> )}

                     </Picker>

                     </View>

    )

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your code, render function calls in a loop because when you pass data to parent, the parent and child will re-render. you can write a function to set states and pass them to parent and call it in `onValueChange` of each picker like this:

```
onChange = (newYear, newMonth, newDay) => {
    const {day, month, year} = this.state
    if (newYear != '') this.setState({ year: newYear }, ()=>{this.props.onChange({day, month, year})})
    if (newMonth != '') this.setState({ month: newMonth }, ()=>{this.props.onChange({day, month, year})})
    if (newDay != '') this.setState({ day: newDay }, ()=>{this.props.onChange({day, month, year})})
}
```

and call it like this:

```
<Picker
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
           this.onChange(itemValue, '', '')
    }>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the state logic in parent component.Pass these values as props to child component.
Here is an example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    a: 0
  };
  updateState = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.setState({
      a: this.state.a + 1
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <App val={this.state.a} updateState={this.updateState} />;
  }
}
function App(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {props.val}
      <div>
        <button onClick={props.updateState}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<A />, rootElement);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3x3vo80zr)

Comment: I want to pass values from multiple components, I can use `props.updateState` for each Picker. but I prefer to have one prop for receiving all of them.